# Framer motion text reveal not animating

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, gsap, framer-motion

I can't find the error on the code, and my text reveal is not working. If I do a simple animation it seems to work, so the error is not on the import or anything because the library is working perfectly:

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const banner = {
  animate: {
    transition: {
      delayChildren: 0.4,
      staggerChildren: 0.1,
    },
  },
};

const letterAni = {
  initial: { y: 400 },
  animate: {
    y: 0,
    transition: {
      ease: [0.6, 0.01, -0.05, 0.95],
      duration: 1,
    },
  },
};

const AnimatedLetters = ({ title }) => (
  <motion.span
    className="row-title"
    variants={banner}
    initial="initial"
    animate="animate"
  >
    {[...title].map((letter, i) => (
      <motion.span className="row-letter" variants={letterAni} key={i}>
        {letter}
      </motion.span>
    ))}
  </motion.span>
);

export default function TestFramer() {
  return (
    <div className="text-9xl">
      <AnimatedLetters title={"title"} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate `x` and `y` properties on inline elements (like `span`). You'd need to use a block-level element there (like `div`), or you can add some styling to tell your spans to behave like block-level elements:

```
<motion.span 
    style={{display: "inline-block"}} 
    className="row-letter" 
    variants={letterAni} 
    key={I}
>
    {letter}
</motion.span>
```